# MySQL stores only "1" (as a value) no matter what numbers I submit in the form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I am trying to create a simple bootstrap form in php and mysql (I use xampp with default settings). Everything is done in 1 file called index.php.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputLongitude" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Longitude</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputLongitude" placeholder="longitude" name="inputLongitude">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputLatitude" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Latitude</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputLatitude" placeholder="latitude" name="inputLatitude">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                               </form>
```

The form is very simple, it takes 2 values and stores them in the db. And here my php code I use to store values in mysql (in the same file - index.php):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'android_app') or die("bla");

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

                $longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']); 
                $lati = isset($_POST['inputLatitude']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`key_primary`, `lati`, `longti`) VALUES (`key_primary`,$lati,$longti)";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Until now almost everything works fine. The both values are saved. 
Here is my setting for db: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxNyD.jpg

**NOW my problem:** Values, which are supposed to be saved (= which I want to submit and store in the db) , are **not** stored. So instead of storing e.g. "50,5" mysql stores **only "1" - always, no matter what** I sent in the form. Take a look here http://imgur.com/brjFn5e.

What is really interesting is that if I use SQL in phpmyadmin and insert values there ("manual way") it is ok. No problem at all. Do you an idea how I can solve that? Is my db setting wrong ? Or it is somewhere in the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs here:

```
$longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']); 
$lati = isset($_POST['inputLatitude']);
```

This block is assigning the truth value of `isset(...)` to `$longti` and `$lati` instead of your intended values from `$_POST`. If you're completely assured of the security of these $_POST values (which you should not be), then you should have:

```
$longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']) ? $_POST['inputLongitude'] : null; 
$lati = isset($_POST['inputLatitude']) ? $_POST['inputLatitude'] : null;
```

If these values are coming from untrusted sources (as `$_POST` values usually are) then you should also perform some validation on the values before outputting them to your db.

Edit: I just noticed `$out = isset($in) ? $in : null;` pattern looks (and is) redundant: `$out = $in;` would perform exactly the same. My usual is to include basic validation/filtering within this step. For instance, if all you're expecting/allowing is a numeric value (since your `<input>` type is 'numeric'):

```
$longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']) && is_numeric($_POST['inputLongitude'])
    ? $_POST['inputLongitude'] : null;
```

or integers only:

```
$longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']) ? (int) $_POST['inputLongitude'] : null;
```

These are simplistic examples that don't include feedback to the user of invalid form content, etc.

Comment: Oh man. Yes it works, thank you very much. I would vote it up, sadly can't. BTW I forgot to mention that i am a beginner in php+mysql. But I will mark it, of course, as resolved.

Comment: Actually, you should ALWAYS at least escape values that go into an SQL string with `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the isset function

```
$longti = isset($_POST['inputLongitude']);
```

the above code does not set the value of $_POST['inputLongitude'] but rather whether $_POST['inputLongitude'] exists... 1 would mean that it exists.

You can simply use:

```
$longti = $_POST['inputLongitude'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lati = isset($_POST['inputLatitude']);
```

This is always 0 or 1 :isset or not.Use if isset blah=someotherblah

```
if (isset($_POST["inputLatitude"])) {
    $lati = $_POST['inputLatitude'];  
}else{  
    echo "N0, inputLatitude is not set";
}
```